# What is the language of the lyrics in "Replica" from Ghost in the Shell?

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtqMOKuUNHs

I couldn't find an answer on google or wikipedia. Copy pasting the lyrics into google translate didn't detect the language either.

Comment: You are most likely right, it's a made up language. I can finally sleep at night

Comment: Could very well be Japanese. When you look up the lyrics, they really are listed as gibberish and I don't think the lyrics are posted correctly. I sat down and listened to this at work writing each word down based on what it initially sounded like and then adjusted for the proper spelling of the corresponding word and this is what I came up with for the first line: Sta ~en kowa ru dame sei ren sajitarita ... I would need help via an official Japanese speech translator, but I could easily see this being Japanese.

Comment: After that is repeated once, the following line could be: Sta ~en kowa ru dame sei ren-sajita karu

Comment: Have you considered that this part is in English and reads "Stalling quiet down my silence"? The linked youtube vid has a translation in its description. It looks bogus, but then again, these songs contain bogus English and Russian which also look pretty broken. This could be the official translation as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: It could be. But if we ran with that translation on the first line being "Stalling quiet down my silence" followed directly with "saji tarita" or さじ足りた, it would literally make no sense. And I am more certain of saji tarita being the actual line used than I am with stalling quiet down my silence before it.

Comment: I am sure that a substantial portion of that song is actually Japanese. However, without a good speech translator, I couldn't say definitively. There were a few words in the song that really seemed out of place, so I'd settle with saying that it's possible this is a mix of languages, or that the words used were just extremely unfamiliar to me. Even as I write the words down from the song, it is apparent that if I mis-hear the syllable, that one syllable change completely alters the translation. Thus, the need for a good Japanese translator would be necessary to know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was puzzled by this question as well and I asked Ilaria Graziano herself if the song's language was real or made up, and she told me it's made up.

Check out the screenshot for proof.

[image: Screenshot from FB Messenger]

Answer (score 2):

Honestly the first line sounds like "Stand in quiet and in silence" to me, with an accent. The rest not too sure on, seems like a blend of words and snippets from other languages. I'm pretty confident in the one line based on listening to "Where dies this ocean go" from the first season of SAC. It's in English but the accent is pretty heavy. The pronunciation is very similar. It's been said in many resources that the singer is not very comfortable with English, though seems to like adding it on occasion.

Answer (score 1):

It's Italian because the singer is [Ilaria Graziano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilaria_Graziano) which is indicated in that youtube vid's description, the song's info on the dics cover if you have it, or on Wikipedia. Also, if you put the lyrics into auto-translator sites, you might get Italian. So many ways to find that out for yourself :p

Update: ok maybe not completely 100% Italian. It is known that some of Yoko Kanno's tracks contain other languages, such as broken English, Russian and the made-up [Gablish](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-the-lyrics-of-yoko-kannos-moon-gibberish-or-intelligible).

Except in case of untranslatable Gablish, there are some translations found on the internet for the lyrics of this song. My theory is that it's because it is in fact at least in part a real language.

So after finding the disc paper scans, I've found that this track definitely has words (duh) unlike some tracks which don't, and have no corresponding description on the track list page:

[image]

listed tracks with words contain:

- 1. player
- 2. replica
- 7. she is
- 8. from the rooftop somewhere in the silence
- 12. date of rebirth
- 13. take a little hand

…but "Replica" and "She is" don't have the lyrics printed on that CD's paper, apparently. For whatever reason!

[This site says](http://fangirlisms.com/2010/04/yoko-kanno-does-not-make-up-languages/) that one of the other songs by Ilaria Graziano is a mix of Italian and English − "I Do" from the 2nd GIG album. So this is probably the same deal here.

I have found this translation on several sites without any source, so take it as is:

```
Stalling quiet down my silence
searching that weve done?
Stalling quiet down my silence
searching that weve done...
Stalling quiet down my silence
Searching for calm...

Found my own destiny out there
Cant you be calm?
Love is broken knitted
thought a love remade
Cheating, stole it, I dont know
Buried, the comatose flower so are growing there
Buried it there my good son
So much to shine over
Like a show that never star
A shamed one will change
Fool got you the nothing
A shamed one will change
Fool got you the nothing
Stalling quiet down my silence
searching that weve done...
I just done all my life...
all my life
all my life
all my life
You should know
You should know
I should know
Should know
My Self... My Self... My Self...
How much would I know My Self...
My Self...
My Self...
Stalling quiet down my silence
searching that weve done?
Stalling quiet down my silence
searching that weve done?
Searching for calm... ehhhhh....
A shamed one will change
A shamed one will change
A shamed one will change
Fool got you the nothing
Fool got you the nothing...
```

Comment: Just because the singer is italian doesn't imply the lyrics are italian. I set google translate to italian and copy pasted the lyrics there. It fails to translate it to english, so.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHC1230OpOg

Comment: This is not Italian, it's impossible. Quaire is not an italian word in any dictionary I used. All attempts to translate words one by one in Wiktionary gives old french as the closest possible answer

Comment: It's definitely a mix of languages though. Maybe you're trying to translate each and every word as Italian, no wonder it doesn't work for the entirety of the lyrics.

Comment: People on the internet are known to make up lyrics and translations thereof for songs that are basically scat-sung. One person somewhere probably pulled the "Stalling quiet down my silence" so-called translation out of their butt and then a million other sites copy-pasted it. (Compare: https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/25827/)